# SubSonic 3 and WebApplication Installation

Tags: subsonic3

Will SubSonic work in Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition, and if it works what is the installation steps.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to be way more specific!

A good starting point is the subsonic examples - http://www.subsonicproject.com/